# common location for test resources in maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, testng

I'm preparing a test env. for my project.
I have a bunch of maven projects and some of the projects are using common configuration for spring beans test (**test-context.xml**). All the tests works when I have this configuration in `src\test\resources` of every project. When I want to move that configuration to a separate project (**project-test**) to eliminate duplicates in every project I get an Exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 39 more
```

- I've added a maven dependency to **project-tests** in the project with tests
- the **test-context.xml** doesn't go to the **target** directory
- when I put my resources in `src/main/resources` instead of `src/test/resources` it works

What is the way to add the test resource from another project so it's visible from a TestNG test?
Is moving it to `src/main/resources` the best way in this situation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing Test code in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174560/sharing-test-code-in-maven)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply have a dependency on project-tests and expect the resource from `src/test/resources` to come through. You will need to build a test JAR from your `project-tests` project. Luckily for you this is quite simple and has been explained very well in another SO thread [Sharing Test code in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174560/sharing-test-code-in-maven)

The basic idea is to generate a test jar file of `project-tests` with a classifier and then use that as a dependency in your project. This approach is best practice for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ramsinb solution is correct. But if you deal only with resources, prefer an assembly which is better designed for this, and share a zip.

- Here guidelines : [Common test data for multiple independent maven projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970120/common-test-data-for-multiple-independent-maven-projects)
- Here an example (see my answer) : [Maven - Depend on assembled zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298178/maven-depend-on-assembled-zip/12299646#12299646)

### Zip Project :

**pom.xml**

```xml
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>cfg_dev</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cfg-main-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>/src/main/assembly/resources.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Assembly descriptor :** 
It will produce this artifact : cfg_dev-1.1.0-resources.zip
Please, note that

1. this is a zip archive
2. the "classifier" is resources (like assembly name)

   resources
     
       zip
     
     false
     
       
         src/main/resources

### Main Project :

**pom.xml**

Please, note that

1. this depends on a zip archive
2. the dependency "classifier" is resources (like previous assembly name)

   ```xml
   <!-- Unit test dependency -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
       <artifactId>cfg_dev</artifactId>
       <version>${project.version}</version>
       <classifier>resources</classifier>
       <type>zip</type>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   ...
   ```

   src/test/resources
               true
           
           
           
               ${project.build.directory}/test-resources
               true

   ```xml
   <plugins>


       <!-- Unzip shared resources -->
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>unpack-cfg-test-resources</id>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                   <configuration>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-resources</outputDirectory>
                       <includeArtifacIds>cfg_dev</includeArtifacIds>
                       <includeGroupIds>${project.groupId}</includeGroupIds>
                       <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                       <excludeTypes>pom</excludeTypes>
                       <scope>test</scope>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   ```